# SQL Server Access Database in Filesystem

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, backup, windows-server

We have a Windows Server 2008 which is offline. We no longer have access to the server OS, or any GUI tools, but we do have a backup of the entire `C:/` of this server.

This server used to host an SQL server instance, and we now need to access of one of the databases on this server, so that we can move it to a new server.

How can we achieve this?

Can we simply copy the `MSSQL/DATA` directory from the backup file to a new server?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/30440/170408

Answer (score 5):

If you can find .mdf and .ldf file you can try to attach it to the new SQL instance using below:

```
CREATE DATABASE <db_name>
    ON (FILENAME = '<mdf file path>'), 
    (FILENAME = '<ldf file path>') 
    FOR ATTACH;
```

Also you can check this solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61954107/how-to-attach-a-database-by-mdf-file-that-has-not-been-detached